# getResource() java Resource folder

Tags: java, resources

[image]

Почему когда я пытаюсь вызвать `ServiceImpl.class.getClassLoader().getResource("coopAccess_db")` 
мне возвращается null а стоит поместить его в папку и  указать соответствующий путь `getResource("db/coopAccess_db")` возвращается нормальный url

Comment: Какой url возвращается?

Comment: В первом случае null во втором
file:/C:/Users/user/Documents/IntelijIdeaRes/IdeaProjects/CoopAccess_Server/target/classes/db/coopAccess_db

Comment: Там есть такой файл?

Comment: конечно я же скрин кинул, но находит файл только если его еще в дополнительную директорию кинуть

Comment: Кокое имя у файла?

Comment: Хм... Не находит именно в корне и именно без расширения, видимо путает с папкой. Задайте имя так: `coopAccess.db` - должен найти.

Comment: Помогло пересоздание проекта(создал новый и кинул в него  src из старого )

Answer (score 0):

Обращайтесь так:

```
    ServiceImpl.class.getResource("/coopAccess_db");
```

Comment: пробовал тоже null

Comment: Проверьте, чтоб файл, который вы ищите лежал в корне jar файла после сборки проекта. Если его там нет, так искать не будет.